# Node-firebird doesn't give results if more than 3 fields in the query

Tags: node.js, firebird, node-firebird

I'm testing "node-firebird" with Firebird 2.5 and it runs if I query for 1, 2 or 3 fields, but if I ask for a fourth field, it doesn't give any response. It is not a problem with any exact field because it queries well if I ask for it with less other fields. Depending on the table the number of fields I can query is different.

```
var Firebird = require('node-firebird');

var options = {};
 
options.host = '127.0.0.1';
options.port = 3050;
options.database = 'xxx.FDB';
options.user = 'SYSDBA';
options.password = 'masterkey';
options.lowercase_keys = false; // set to true to lowercase keys
options.role = null;            // default
options.pageSize = 4096;        // default when creating database


Firebird.attach(options, function(err, db) {

    if (err)
        throw err;


    db.query('SELECT fiel1, field2, field3_act FROM table', function(err, result) {
 
        console.log("result", result)

        db.detach();
    });

 
});
```

Comment: This question was also crossposted to https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird/issues/216

Comment: Is Henri still active? i feel he quite FLOSS development long ago, first from Delphi then from JS too @MarkRotteveel

Comment: @wakeup what does http://FBProfiler.sf.net report? Does Firebird server receive the query with 4 fields or not ?

Comment: @Arioch'The The last version was released 10 days ago, by mariuz who also has commit rights to that repository.